# Python Pyqt5 QDateEdit Get Date String

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5, qdateedit

I'm trying to build a date printer using Pyqt5 QDateEdit. I can popup the calendar, but I want to write the clicked date's string in the console (or in a label in window). I tried `print(self.calendarWidget().document().toPlainText())` or `print(self.calendarWidget().currentText())` but it didn't work.

I use this code;

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class DateEdit(QtWidgets.QDateEdit):
    popupSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(DateEdit, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setCalendarPopup(True)
        self.calendarWidget().installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if self.calendarWidget() is obj and event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Show:
            self.popupSignal.emit()
        return super(DateEdit, self).eventFilter(obj, event)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = DateEdit()
    w.popupSignal.connect(lambda: print("popup"))
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

What is its syntax? I didn't find enough documentation for it. Can you help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT: The answer**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.dateEdit = QDateEdit(self)
        self.lbl = QLabel()
        self.dateEdit.setMaximumDate(QtCore.QDate(7999, 12, 28))
        self.dateEdit.setMaximumTime(QtCore.QTime(23, 59, 59))
        self.dateEdit.setCalendarPopup(True)

        layout = QGridLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.dateEdit)
        layout.addWidget(self.lbl)
        self.setLayout(layout)


        self.dateEdit.dateChanged.connect(self.onDateChanged)

    def onDateChanged(self, qDate):
        print('{0}/{1}/{2}'.format(qDate.day(), qDate.month(), qDate.year()))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName('MyWindow')

    main = MyWindow()
    main.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: @S.Nick something unnecessary function that I forgot to delete, thank you for remind me, I deleted now

Comment: I don’t know about the exact syntax in python, but QDate has a toString() method taking the date format as argument, and QLocale has functions to get a date formatted according to the user’s locale.